# Automatically exit Visual Build Professional tool when build is done?

Tags: visual-build-professional

Visual Build Professional has an [Exit] action but it only terminates the build currently in progress. Is there any way for it to terminate the entire build tool?

I have a frequently run build script which I usually let run in the background, and it would be convenient if the tool would clean itself up by terminating altogether once this build is done.

Answer (score 1):

Include the /s flag when starting VisBuildPro.exe (if using a VisBuildPro Project action, check 'Run GUI App in silent mode' on the Project tab) so that it will exit after the build finishes.

https://kinook.com/VisBuildPro/Manual/command_linegui.htm

You may also want to check 'Tools | User Options | Build | Honor command-line switches if build fails/canceled and continued'.

https://kinook.com/VisBuildPro/Manual/builduseropt.htm

Comment: This will work, but means I can't simply double click the script to get the desired behavior. Wrapping it in a batch file or similar would work... but is slightly less convenient.

Comment: Add /s to the shell command in the registry at HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\VisualBuildPro9.Project\shell\open\command

Answer (score 0):

Similar to [running the GUI tool with a command line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53598909/3195477), another possibility is to run the build script using the `VisBuildCmd.exe` command line executor.

Details: https://www.kinook.com/VisBuildPro/Manual/index.htm?consoleapp.htm

This does not quite meet the question's objective of having the script itself cause the build tool to terminate, and would require either running the command manually at a prompt or otherwise scripting it like with a batch file. However once setup this achieves nearly the same result.